# How do I test scala.js programs for side-effects that happen asynchronously using µtest?

Tags: scala.js, utest

I have a µtest suite that needs to check that some asynchronous operation eventually has a side effect. Since javascript (and thus scala.js) is single threadded, it is not possible to block and wait for the side effect to happen. Also, the µtest `eventually` method does not work on javascript runtime. How do I perform such a test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return a `Future` from a µtest, then the test will pass if the future succeeds and fail if the future fails. Thus, you can schedule the conditional check for some point in the future without blocking.

I wrote a simple `eventually` method that accomplishes this:

```
package utest

import rx.ops.DomScheduler

import scala.concurrent.{Promise, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object JsOps {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val scheduler = new DomScheduler

  def eventually(eval: => Try[Boolean])(implicit timeout: FiniteDuration): Future[Boolean] = {
    val p = Promise[Boolean]()
    scheduler.scheduleOnce(timeout) {
      eval match {
        case Success(b) => p.success(b)
        case Failure(t) => p.failure(t)
      }
    }
    p.future
  }
}
```

Here is an example of usage:

```
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  implicit val timeout = 30.milliseconds

  eventually {
    if (/*condition holds true*/) {
      Success(true)
    } else Failure(new RuntimeException(/*error message*/))
  }
```